# Why would I get a Windows Authentication error when using WindowsIdentity User.Value. The 'Value' property is missing at runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, authentication, iis

I am experiencing an issue where I cannot perform an LDAP lookup to find the groups a user is assigned because the (WindowsIdentity)User.Value property is missing at runtime. It's not null, just not there, but the User value is not null.

There is a specific scenario at work here: The WebServer is on a network that is only accessible by Remote Desktop.

To get onto the network I use a Jump Server, So Remote Desktop to the Jump Server and then Remote desktop to other servers in the network, including the WebServer.

The WebServer has a Windows Authenticate MVC (Framework 4.8) Application running as the default Website on IIS (wwwroot), and is accessible on the network via it's machine name: https://machineName. Therefore, when logged on to the WebServer it is available from https://localhost.

When logged on to the Server and calling https://localhost everything is fine. The user is authenticated and I can do the LDAP call to query what groups they have.

When calling the site from the Jump Server using https://machineName IIS authenticates, but I can't  do the LDAP call to query what groups users have.

I have the following code:

```
public static AdUser GetAdUser(this WindowsIdentity Id)
{
      try
      {
          if (Id.User == null)
          {
              throw new Exception("AdUser GetAdUser(this WindowsIdentity) User is null");
          }
          else
          {
              return Id.User.GetAdUser();
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          throw new Exception("Error retrieving AD User", ex);
      }
}
public static AdUser GetAdUser(this SecurityIdentifier User)
{
    try
    {
        if (User.Value != null)
        {
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
            {
                if (context != null)
                {
                    var principal = new UserPrincipal(context);
                    if (principal != null)
                    {
                        var account = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Sid, User.Value);
                        if (account != null)
                        {
                            return account.Adapt(new AdUser());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception("GetAdUser(this SecurityIdentifier User) UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Sid, User.Value) is null");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         throw new Exception("GetAdUser(this SecurityIdentifier User) new UserPrincipal(context) is null");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("GetAdUser(this SecurityIdentifier User) PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain) context is null");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("GetAdUser(this SecurityIdentifier User) User.Value is null");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error retrieving AD User", ex);
    }
}
```

The first extension method checks (Id.User == null) so the User is not null and then moves on to return Id.User.GetAdUser();

In the next method is the statement if (User.Value != null). It is here the code breaks. User is not null, the property seems not to exist.

In IIS I have only Windows Authentication enabled with the sole provider of NTLM.

I would be grateful to discover the cause.

This code uses the SID to FindByIdentity but this error exists no matter what IdentityType I use.

Comment: Can you post the full error message? It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error was on line:

```
var account = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Sid, User.Value);
```

And the stack trace last method was system.directoryservices.directoryentry.bind(boolean throwiffail)

The servers have different authentication types, the jump server authenticates with AuthenticationType:Kerberos and the webServer uses AuthenticationType:Negotiate.

The site runs under the NetworkService account and I suspect the error is related to impersonating the authenticated user to read from AD, and it's fails  with AuthenticationType:Kerberos

UPDATE: the following statement causes the error below

```
UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName
```

Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'.